# TSQL: No value instead of Null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, null

Due to a weird request, I can't put `null` in a database if there is no value. I'm wondering what can I put in the store procedure for nothing instead of `null`.

For example:

```
insert into blah (blah1) values (null)
```

Is there something like nothing or empty for "blah1" instead using `null`?

Comment: What is the table definition? What is the error message?

Comment: Don't downvote this; it's a frequently encountered issue in RL with real users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would push back on this bizarre request.  That's exactly what `NULL` is for in SQL, to denote a missing or inapplicable value in a column.

Is the requester experiencing grief over SQL logic with `NULL`?

**edit:**  Okay, I've read your reply with the extra detail about this job assignment (btw, generally you should edit your original question instead of posting more information in an answer).

You'll have to declare all columns as `NOT NULL` and designate a special value in the domain of that column's data type to signify "no value."  The appropriate value to choose might be different on a case by case basis, i.e. zero may signify nothing in a `person_age` column, but it might have significance in an `items_in_stock` column.

You  should document the no-value value for each column.  But I suppose they don't believe in documentation either.  :-(

Comment: I agree. It's weird request. They use Access for DB so i guess that's telling you something. The guy that i'm working for told me they hate null in the db. They prefer it to be nothing but isn't nothing basically mean null?

Comment: Yes, NULL indicates the absence of a value, so that you don't have to designate one value (which you might need later) to signify 'nothing.'

Comment: They need to be more specific than they "hate null."  I hate division by zero exceptions, but I don't stop using zero.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the data type of the column. For numbers (integers, etc) it could be zero (0) but if varchar then it can be an empty string ("").

I agree with other responses that NULL is best suited for this because it transcends all data types denoting the absence of a value. Therefore, zero and empty string might serve as a workaround/hack but they are fundamentally still actual values themselves that might have business domain meaning other than "not a value".

(If only the SQL language supported [a "Not Applicable" (N/A) value type that would serve as an alternative to NULL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)#Criticisms)...)

Comment: Unless it is a field for which zero is a valid value.  You would not want a field that stores temperature to default to zero.

Comment: @TGnat- yes. good point. i needed to update my response to reflect the inherent weekness of that approach.

Comment: (I've read that in the early days of SQL there was a proposal to have two "NULL" values -- one for absent value, and one for inapplicable.)

Comment: @Bill Karwin- yup. i recalled the same and add a link to wikipedia mentioning that.  ("..."Missing but Applicable" and "Missing but Inapplicable", known as A-values and I-values,..")

Answer (score 0):

Is null is a valid value for whatever you're storing?

- Use a sentry value like INT32.MaxValue, empty string, or "XXXXXXXXXX" and assume it will never be a legitimate value
- Add a bit column 'Exists' that you populate with true at the same time you insert.

**Edit:** But yeah, I'll agree with the other answers that trying to change the requirements might be better than trying to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a varchar or equivalent field, then use the empty string.

If you're using a numeric field such as int then you'll have to force the user to enter data, else come up with a value that means NULL.

I don't envy you your situation.

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between NULLs as assigned values (e.g. inserted into a column), and NULLs as a SQL artifact (as for a field in a missing record for an OUTER JOIN. Which might be a foreign concept to these users. Lots of people use Access, or any database, just to maintain single-table lists.) I wouldn't be surprised if naive users would prefer to use an alternative for assignments; and though repugnant, it should work ok. Just let them use whatever they want.

Answer (score 0):

There is some validity to the requirement to not use NULL values. NULL values can cause a lot of headache when they are in a field that will be included in a JOIN or a WHERE clause or in a field that will be aggregated.

Some SQL implementations (such as MSSQL) disallow NULLable fields to be included in indexes.

MSSQL especially behaves in unexpected ways when NULL is evaluated for equality. Does a NULL value in a PaymentDue field mean the same as zero when we search for records that are up to date? What if we have names in a table and somebody has no middle name. It is conceivable that either an empty string or a NULL could be stored, but how do we then get a comprehensive list of people that have no middle name?

In general I prefer to avoid NULL values. If you cannot represent what you want to store using either a number (including zero) or a string (including the empty string as mentioned before) then you should probably look closer into what you are trying to store. Perhaps you are trying to communicate more than one piece of data in a single field.